# How to modify a Linux Kernel driver which is NOT compiled as a module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm trying to modify the touchscreen driver of an embedded device in order to have multitouch support. The thing is that this driver is originally NOT compiled as a module, and so I don't know any way to change it beside a complete kernel rebuild. This is not really what I'd like to do. I've tried to modify the existing driver and compile it as a module; after having changed the name, it loads without complaining, but no event gets reported beside the ones output by the original driver. Is there any better way to do what I want? Any particular reason this could not be working?

Comment: An important thing to add is that this is an i2c driver, and it seems things are a little different. I can unbind the driver as @msh said but when I do:
`insmod /mnt/onboard/zforce_i2c_multitouch.ko
echo zforce 0x50 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device`
I still get:
`i2c i2c-0: Failed to register i2c client zforce at 0x50 (-16)`

Answer (score 4):

You can try to manually unbind the original driver before loading your module. See [this LWN post](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, really interesting. I can unbind the original driver without problems, and the device /dev/input/event0 that was associated with it disappears; however, if I load my own driver and bind the hardware to it, such device doesn't get created, and as such I can't get any output... anything to check?

Comment: I can create the device manually with mknod: `mknod /dev/input/event1 c 13 65` but I then get: `[root@(none) /]# cat /dev/input/event1
cat: can't open '/dev/input/event1': No such device`

Comment: Are you sure the major/minor numbers are right for your driver?  Also beware of getting a in revert-war with whatever Android daemon normally manages device node creation.

Comment: according to this [link](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devices.txt) major and minor should be right. I'm not on androd but on a linux-based ebook reader. Maybe udev is already doing something but at least no entry under /dev gets created automatically.

Comment: I've found that my "bind" does nothing, and I verified it by unbinding and binding again the original driver. `echo -n "0-0050" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/zforce-ir-touch/unbind` works, but `echo -n "0-0050" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/zforce-ir-touch/bind` does nothing. How's that possible?